# Using `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:`, how do i found that characters are mismatch?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitextfield

I'm using the code below for setting validation of textfield as it should not enter above 15 character length .

```
 let limitLength = 15

 func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

    // set maximum length for password and confirm password
    if textField == txtPassword { // if textfield password is editing

        guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
        let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
        return newLength <= limitLength

    } else if textField == txtConfirmpassword { // if textfield confirm password is editing
        guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
        let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length
        return newLength <= limitLength
    }
    return true
}
```

there are two textfield as password and confirm password 
i want to check validation whether they have same string or not?

"textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange" is method we need to use but i don't know how to compare while user is entering and i need to display alert message that they are not same 
Note :- it should not compare while click on any button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

// set maximum length for password and confirm password
if textField == txtPassword { // if textfield password is editing

    guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
    let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count
    return newLength <= limitLength

} else if textField == txtConfirmpassword { // if textfield confirm password is editing
    guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
    let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count
    if newLength <= limitLength && txtPassword.text.hasPrefix("\(text)\(string)") {
    return true
} else {
   // here u can show alert
     textField.resignFirstResponder()
     return false
 }
      }
        return true
   }
```

Comment: else {  // here u can show alert
     return false
 }

Comment: but the thing is its checking length first. what i want is suppose password having string like "123456789" now and when user is about to enter in confirm password with 1 it should show error .and the error will display till password and confirm password not match

Comment: let newLength = text.characters.count + string.characters.count - range.length

Comment: here remove the range.length

Comment: once check my answer i removed that range deduction

Comment: do u know telugu?

Comment: no no anna but i m huge fan of south movies thanks for help

Comment: I appreciate it. :)

Comment: How do you came to know that I'm from south?

Comment: Suryanarayana was my room owner and he belongs from kerala ..:)